# Is there a method for handling errors from COM objects in RDML?

Tags: com, error-handling

Is there a method for handling errors from COM objects in RDML? For instance, when calling Word VBA methods like `PasteSpecial`, an error is returned and the LANSA application crashes. I cannot find anything in the documentation to allow handling of these errors.

Actually, error handling in general is a weak-point for LANSA and RDML, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

I know almost nothing about LANSA etc. A few minutes in Google convinced me that error handling is, as you say, not a strong point. Over on the lansa.us site there is this article about [remote debugging](http://lansa.us/support/tips/t0415.htm) which, at a stretch, might be going in the right direction.

One wonders if a DEF_BREAK would work. Here's [a longish post about using DEF_BREAK](http://www.can-da.com/canda/articles/articles/lansa1/levels.html). If DEF_BREAK hooks in with #COM_* functions, that might be a possibility. Please pardon my naivety in this regard.

I also found some code at the [LANSA Tech Exchange](http://www.lansa.com.au/support/exchange/available.htm). I had hoped that there'd be something obvious, but no. Being more LANSA-aware than me, you may find something.

Answer (score 1):

At my company, we were able to handle Communication API's through the ActiveX part of LANSA. The supplier embedded his API's in an ActiveX component. We used this component in our LANSA application. This works fine and stable.

Maybe you could embed the Microsoft API's in an ActiveX component too? I don't know from the top of my head if Microsoft Word can be addressed as an ActiveX component.